# Firebase Recyclerview Adapter and Firebase UI database

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, android-recyclerview, firebaseui

I am new to Coding and learning Android Studio through udemy and online videos. I had no problem till now.

I am using Android 3.5.3. I have enabled Androidx when I was starting a new project. As I am using **FirebaseRecyclerviewAdapter** in my project to retrieve data from database and list it. But FBR adapter is not recognised in the code and shows error.

Hence I am trying to implement the below support dependency

```
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0'
```

I was shown following errors when I sync *build.gradle* file

**ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download auto-value-annotations.jar (com.google.auto.value:auto-value-annotations:1.6.5)
ERROR: Unable to resolve dependency for ':app@debugUnitTest/compileClasspath': Could not download firebase-ui-common.aar (com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-common:6.1.0)**

Please someone guide me how to implement the above dependency or how to make **FirebaseRecyclerviewAdapter** recognized in the code.

**build.gradle (Module)**

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 29
    buildToolsVersion "29.0.2"
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.vcred"
        minSdkVersion 18
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "androidx.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility = 1.8
        targetCompatibility = 1.8
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
    implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
    implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:16.0.5'
    implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:16.0.4'
    testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
    implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
    implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
    implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha01'

     implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0'
}
```

**build.gradle (project)**

```
// Top-level build file where you can add configuration options common to all sub-projects/modules.

buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()


    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.5.3'
        classpath 'com.google.gms:google-services:4.2.0'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()


    }
}

task clean(type: Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}
```

Anyone is there to rescue me from the issue which I am facing for which I am unable to find any solution online or in this forum too till now. Hope I would be able to complete my test project with the help of experts in this forum.

Answer (score 0):

I was able to sort out the issue and finally dependencies were synced in the build.gradle file.

The dependencies in the build.gradle file is given below.

```
implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])
implementation 'androidx.appcompat:appcompat:1.1.0'
implementation 'androidx.lifecycle:lifecycle-extensions:2.1.0'
testImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.ext:junit:1.1.1'
androidTestImplementation 'androidx.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.2.0'
implementation 'androidx.cardview:cardview:1.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.android.material:material:1.2.0-alpha03'
implementation 'androidx.recyclerview:recyclerview:1.2.0-alpha01'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:19.2.0'
implementation 'com.firebaseui:firebase-ui-database:6.2.0'
```